# Task to convert natural language query to SQL query

Tags: python, sql, database, nltk

I have a task where I have to convert natural language query such is "what is the number of soap in inventory?" to `select count(item) from inventory where item="Soap" group by item` .

I am trying to implement this using python. Any lead on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Posting these in case you haven't already run across them: 1) https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31617/natural-language-to-sql-query, 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819075/what-are-some-of-the-ways-to-convert-nlp-to-sql

Comment: Converting one phrase to an equivalent is an advanced NLP concept in itself. The question should probably be rewritten including the references posted by ravioli and explaining that you want to do the reverse. Otherwise, why not "replace" `select` with `What is the`, `count(item)` with `number of items and `where item=` with `where the item is` ?

Comment: BTW `datascience` would be a better place to ask how to reverse NLP to SQL conversion

Comment: Thanks for the help. The links proved to be very much fruit full @ravioli

Comment: Great, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still looking for answers. There is branch of computer science called Natural Language Interface to Data Bases (NLIDB), where different techniques are proposed (Machine Learning, Rule based grammars).

Chatbots also solve a similar problem: use "Intent Classification" to determine what the query is about, and fills in a frame with information deduced from the query. Then in the action part, produce the corresponding query. In real life, many NL query can correspond to the same SQL. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rasa.